# Solving for 170 Variables in MS Excel

Tags: excel

**More so a logic question than code question**

I'm currently working on identifying how long a given product our plant produces takes. Rather than going out and conducting a time study, I'd rather take historical SAP data and fit our product output numbers to find an estimated time that each product takes to make. Problem is that we produce a wide variety of products at this facility.

Here was my logic:

1. Gather all production data for the last six months
2. Create a variable for each product
3. Create equations of Quantity * Variable for each product
4. Add all the individual product equations and set them equal to shift time
   [( a1 * 600 ) + (a2 * 560) + ....] = 480 minutes
5. Hopefully let excel figure out each of the variables.

[image]

The issue I'm having is:

1. How to programatically make the equations for each of the date changes
2. Also I realize Excel probably isn't going to be able to do this too well. So I'll probably then take the equations over to Python to solve - unless someone has a suggestion on how to get Excel to compute through this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The solver could do this, but I think the “standard” solver has a varable limit - Frontline do do, or did do, an extended version so perhaps you could check it out...

Comment: Just curious.. " how long a given product our plant produces takes" <-- I only see 'posting date' data.. To answer how long = need 'from date' + 'to date' data right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, mathematically, just sum up the multiplier for a1 to a13, then using weight, map it back to 48 minutes (or 1920 seconds) .

From your data.. I got :

`1500*a1 + 560*a2 + 56*a3 + 85*a4 + 85*a5 + 164*a6 + 150*a7 + 1*a8 + 10*a9 + 189*a10 + 20*a11 + 45*a12 + 280*a13`

sum up the multiplier :

`1500 + 560 + 56 + 85 + 85 + 164 + 150 + 1 + 10 + 189 + 20 + 45 + 280 = 3145`

weight it to 1920 seconds :

a1 : `1500/3145 * 1920 = 915.7392686804452 secs`

a2 : `560/3145 * 1920 = 341.8759936406995 secs`

...

a13 : `280/3145 * 1920 = 170.9379968203498 secs`

Hope it helps. (: